# Java: Eclipse does not recognize the source folder

Tags: java, eclipse

I don't know what happened, but suddenly Eclipse does not recognize the source folders of all my projects as source any more.

Eclipse treats it like a normal folder, like config e.g.

Can you help me with my problem?

Thanks for your help!!

[image]

Comment: could you share the sub-folders inside src and also your pom.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have changed the *View* (probably you're on the `Navigator` one).

Navigate to `Window` → `Show View` → `Package Explorer` and then the *Package Explorer* view, which marks every source folder with a special icon, will be opened.